# Form loaded from event trigger oncreated (FileSystemWatcher) hangs. C#

Tags: c#

After some help with the following scenario.

I have a FileSystemWatcher

```
 private FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
```

Defined as such

```
watcher.Path = this.pdfStoragePath;
watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastAccess
                                  | NotifyFilters.LastWrite
                                  | NotifyFilters.FileName
                                  | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName
                                  | NotifyFilters.Size;
watcher.Filter = "*.pdf";
watcher.Created += OnCreated;
```

That I have only the "onCreated" event used. When the oncreated event occurs I Do the Following

```
private void OnCreated(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
   messageStatusWindow($"FILE: NEW PDF CREATED {e.FullPath} 
   {e.ChangeType} ");
   
   promptForPrint();
}
```

The prompt for print is a simple form that has 1 label, 2 buttons YES and NO

```
void promptForPrint()
{
        messageStatusWindow("INFO: Opening Paper Receipt Printing Selection...");
        printingPrompt printPrompt = new printingPrompt();
        printPrompt.Show();
        printPrompt.Activate();
}
```

I would like to have the user press a yes or no (return true/false) button within this form to print - the problem being is it seems to just open the form and hangs

There is a status in the output window indicating that a thread has completed which I am assuming is the filewatcher thread leaving me with an orphaned form by the looks.

I am not sure what is the best way to attack this, but the filewatcher waits for a file creation (from external source) and is paramount to the logic of this project.

Any hints appreciated

Comment: Creating a dialog in a thread is not a good idea, that needs to be done on the main (ui) thread. If you want more advice you should show all the code.

Comment: So just say I had a thread run and complete, this thread was triggered by an event outside the main ui, how can I get this to notify either the main ui thread or some interactive prompt to the the user. Creating a dialogue in the thread might be the problem (or not a good idea as you say) but how any suggestions of how a thread notifys the main ui that something has completed. ie like when a web browser is downloading multiple files that would have to be threaded as such

Comment: If you are using WPF you can call Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(myAction).

Comment: Your problem happens because you try to show a non-modal dialog in a thread other than the main UI thread. That in turn happens because `FileSystemWatcher` raises its events in a thread pool thread, unless you set `SynchronizingObject`. See marked duplicate. Setting the property to an appropriate Winforms object (e.g. your form instance) will cause the events to be raised in the main UI thread, where your attempts to access UI objects will work correctly.

Comment: OK thanks - will have a look thanks for the input

Comment: Please mark this as correct answer - thank you so much for your assistance - much appreciated.